# How to use a variable's value as a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 6 UILabels as IBOutlets named tutorialLabel1, tutorialLabel2, etc... I want to bring them all to front using a loop. Here is my code:

```
var tempLabel = "tutorialLabel"
for var i=1; i<=6; i++ {
    tempLabel = "tutorialLabel" + String(i)
    self.tempLabel.bringSubviewToFront(self.tempLabel)
}
```

But it returns the error

> tempLabel is not a member of view.

I think I need to use valueForKey function here but not sure how to implement it in Swift. Can you help me write that line of code?

Comment: You're going to have to explain more here. What is `String(i)`? Why do you have something called `tempLabel` that is a string and then something called `tempLabel` that is trying to be a `UIView`? Also, what are you trying to "bring to front". I doubt that `self.tempLabel` is a `subview` of `self.tempLabel` because they are the same thing. **Forget about the code. What is it you are trying to do? Just explain what you're doing instead of asking how to fix this code.**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to dynamically create a name that references your labels, you can use an IBOutletCollection:

```
@IBOutlet var viewsToBringToFront: [UIView]!
```

You can connect all the views that you will want to bring to the front to that collection and simply loop through it to bring them to the front:

```
for view in viewsToBringToFront {
    view.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(view)
}
```

Comment: but then how would I individually show/hide these labels when needed?

Comment: @KiZ you could either maintain the individual outlets as well, or you could add a "tag" in interface builder so that you can loop through the IBOutletCollection to find a specific view.